How to securely use Remote Desktop Connection to connect from my work computer to my home PC?
My home computer is connected to a wireless router and then to a modem. I tried to connect to my home computer from my work PC [with RDC] by punching in the IP address of my home computer, and that didn't work. The home computer didn't respond. I read that I need to set up port forwarding but that opens up to a high probability of getting hacked. What's the best way to securely use Remote Desktop Connection in this scenario to connect to my home computer? Thank you!

@John What does "commerical VPN" have to do with reaching to one's home / private network?

Assuming you are given a public IP by your ISP, typically the way would be to set up a VPN server on some LAN host (could be the computer itself, or the router if it's a "versatile" one) and expose the VPN server instead. If you aren't, you'll need to set up one somewhere else (e.g., some VPS or so), and connect both the home computer and your work PC to the VPN server.

Port Forwarding in this case is inevitable, if you must use RDC. However, RDC is secure if you're up-to-date. It's encrypted.
However, if you tunnel the connection through SSL it will encrypt the traffic and ensure it's genuine using certificates. (This can be useful on older implementations, as there was a weakness that's been exploited and patched). How it does so is a bit much to go over here, but here's a link explaining it in more detail: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-ssl/
A guide to set this SSL/RDP connection up can be found here: https://security.berkeley.edu/education-awareness/securing-remote-desktop-rdp-system-administrators
